# Prevent content from overlapping scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

Is there a way to add styles directly to the scrollbar so that it will always be on top of the content?

I have an issue where the page loads fine but if I resize the browser window then the header tag shows on top of the scrollbar.

I have the header tag position: fixed and z-index:15000 to ensure the content scrolls underneath it. Also on the body tag I have overflow:auto.

Any help will be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: A fiddle or link would probably make it easier to help you.

Comment: I know but I'm battling to replicate the problem locally and the test version is not available publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style causing this was body { overflow:auto} I removed this and made do without it. There was inconsistencies between the browsers that made this complicated.

Answer (score 0):

All other things being equal, scrollbars **do** render on top of content.  Any other effect would be coming from **something else** in your code, which is why we need your code to help you.

Based on the small example you provided, try removing `position: fixed;` from the element.  See http://jsfiddle.net/rgeFa/.

Comment: Hi, removing Fixed does definitely work but I need the header to be fixed. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: I can't add anything more without seeing a code demonstration.